# references in c++ problem

Tags: c++

I heard references in c++ can be intitalized only once but this is giving me 1 is my output and not returning any error!

```
 struct f { 
   f(int& g) : h(g) { 
     h = 1; 
   }

   ~f() { 
     h = 2; 
   } 

   int& h; 
 };

 int i() { 
   int j = 3; 
   f k(j); 
   return j;
 }
```

Comment: Didn't know that structs can be used in the same way as classes in C++. Good question..

Comment: Nils: The only difference between a struct and a class in C++ is default accessibility. For classes the default is private, but for structs the default is public. For compatibility with C, methinks...

Comment: It's not an issue with reference but with scoping and object life-time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The destructor of f is called after the return value j is captured.

You might want something like this, if you wanted j to be 2:

```
int i( )  
{  
    int j=3;  
    {
        f k(j);  
    }
    return j; 
}
```

See [C++ destructor & function call order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196327/c-destructor-function-call-order) for a more detailed description of the order of destruction and the return statement.

Answer (score 5):

You are still initializing the reference only once; assignment and initialization are not the same. The initialization sets up `h` so that it references `j` (which you never change). Your assignment merely changes the value of `j` which is the same as `h`, but does not cause `h` to refer to a different variable.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code is only to display the issue, storing a reference to a variable defined outside of the class is very dangerous as your class doesn't have any control over (or knowlege of) when the referenced variable goes out of scope.